# check for two values in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table where I store some data related to a user.

| id | id_user | id_func |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

I want to check if a specific user has two specific functions (1 AND 2) assigned. So If I check for user 1 the query will return true. For user 2 it will return false.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT IF(
    "SELECT id_user FROM funz_abilitate WHERE id_func=1 AND id_func=2 AND id_user=1", 
    true, 
    false
) as verifica
FROM funz_abilitate 
WHERE id_user=1
```

but this is returning for user 1:

| verifica |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |

and for user 2:

| verifica |
| --- |
| 0 |

While I'd like just to get a boolean true/false. So if I select user 1 it returns true, if I select user 2 it returns false

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = 2 AS verifica 
FROM funz_abilitate 
WHERE id_user = 1 AND id_func IN (1, 2)
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_func) = 2 AS verifica 
FROM funz_abilitate 
WHERE id_user = 1 AND id_func IN (1, 2)
```

if there are duplicate `id_func`s for each user.

In MySql 8.0+ I would use a `CTE` which returns the `id_func`s I search for, so there is no need to write how many they are:

```
WITH cte(id_func) AS (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2))
SELECT COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS verifica 
FROM funz_abilitate 
WHERE id_user = 1 AND id_func IN (SELECT id_func FROM cte)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d47a3a7924e641b57ee3ecdedac7cfd).

Comment: it works fine also in mysql 8. Thank you very much for the lesson I've just learned!

Comment: @LelioFaieta If you are using MySql 8.0+ check the 3d query in my edited answer.